# Write a file and read same file immediately on windows in Python

Tags: python, windows

We ran into problems when we had 2 separate threads writing and reading the same file at the same time and solved this by removing the read action.

But now we also have a single thread that writes a file and immediately reads the same file back.
To be sure that this is not also prone to cause problems later on, I was looking for information that will assure that this is ok to do. Though I was unable to find it.

Can someone point me to what is and isn't guaranteed when writing/reading files on windows from Python?

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at a multi-threading tool/object called semaphores, https://www.javatpoint.com/python-semaphore

Comment: What are you worried about? There shouldn't be any problems sequentially writing and reading a file in a single thread. It's very different from the multithreaded situation.

Comment: @JussiNurminen: That answers my question. Though it is hard to find any documentation on this.

Comment: @esteenbrink well, as a rule of thumb, running multiple threads can cause a lot of problems (deadlocks, race conditions etc.) that simply do not occur with single-threaded programs.